# Posterior distribution and bayesian inference

Tags: bayesian, posterior

[image]

[image]

I use the formula for posterior distribution, 
$$ \pi(\theta | s) = \frac{\pi(\theta) f_\theta(s)}{m(s)}
$$
And for $\theta = 1, s = 1$,
$$\pi(1)=\frac{1}{5}, f_1(1)=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$ m(s) = \sum\limits_{\Omega} \pi(1)f_1(1) = \sum\limits_{1}^{3} \frac{1}{10} = \frac{3}{10}$$

My answers is $\frac{1}{3}$ but its supposed to be $\frac{3}{16}$. Can someone explain where I'm going wrong?

Comment: For one thing, you haven't calculated it based on a sample of size 2.

Comment: @jbowman how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

$\pi(\theta|x) \propto  f(x|\theta) \pi(\theta)$

so based on sample size to

\begin{array} {c |c c c  } 
   f(x|\theta)  & f(1,1) & f(1,2) & f(2,2)  \\
 \hline 
\theta=1 & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4}\\ 
\theta=2 & \frac{1}{9} & \frac{4}{9} & \frac{4}{9} \\ 
\theta=3 & \frac{9}{16} & \frac{6}{16} & \frac{1}{16}\\  
\end{array}

\begin{array} {c |c   } 
     & \pi(\theta)  \\
 \hline 
\theta=1 & \frac{1}{5} \\ 
\theta=2 & \frac{2}{5} \\ 
\theta=3 & \frac{2}{5} \\  
\end{array}

so

\begin{array} {c |c c c  } 
  \pi (\theta|x) \propto  & (1,1) & (1,2) & (2,2)  \\
 \hline 
\theta=1 & \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{5}=.05   & \frac{1}{2}\times \frac{1}{5}=.1 & \frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{5}=.05\\ 
\theta=2 & \frac{1}{9} \times \frac{2}{5}=0.04444 & \frac{4}{9}\times \frac{2}{5}=0.1778 & \frac{4}{9} \times \frac{2}{5} =0.1778\\ 
\theta=3 & \frac{9}{16}  \times \frac{2}{5}=0.225 & \frac{6}{16} \times \frac{2}{5}=0.15 & \frac{1}{16}\times \frac{2}{5}=0.025\\
\hline 
sum & 0.3194 &  0.4278 & 0.2528 \\
\end{array}

\begin{array} {c |c c c  } 
  \pi (\theta|x) =  & (1,1) & (1,2) & (2,2)  \\
 \hline 
\theta=1 & 0.05/0.3194   & 0.1/0.4278 & 0.05/0.2528\\ 
\theta=2 & 0.04444/0.3194 & 0.1778/0.4278 & 0.1778/0.2528 \\ 
\theta=3 & 0.225/0.3194 & 0.15/0.4278 & 0.025/0.2528
\end{array}

To check one of them:

\begin{eqnarray}
\pi(\theta=1|x=(1,1)) &=& \frac{P(X=(1,1)|\theta=1) \times \pi (\theta=1)}{P((1,1)|\theta=1) \times \pi (\theta=1)
+P((1,1)|\theta=2) \times \pi (\theta=2)
+P((1,1)|\theta=3) \times \pi (\theta=3)
} 
\\
&=& \frac{\frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{5}}{\frac{1}{4} \times \frac{1}{5}
+\frac{1}{9} \times \frac{2}{5}
+\frac{9}{16}  \times \frac{2}{5}
} =\frac{0.05}{0.3194}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: With respect to your first table - shouldn't the probability for $(1,2)$ be the same as for $(2,1)$?

Comment: tnx. you are right. they are a mistake. it is $(2,2)$.